# getting database error on form validation in djongo

Tags: django, error-handling

i have create a custom user model in django using djongo driver
and whenever i tries to add a user with same name or email
is show this error but i want to show them error on form
i also have a post model which uses the user model class as foreign key
so whenever i try to add post with user i

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
       
        username = models.CharField(
            _("username"),
            max_length=150,
            unique=True,
            help_text=_(
                "Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."
            ),
            validators=[UnicodeUsernameValidator],
            error_messages={
                "unique": _("A user with that username already exists."),
            },
            primary_key=True
        )
        email = models.EmailField(
            _("email address"),
            max_length=150,
            unique=True,
            error_messages={
                "unique": _("A user with that email address already exists."),
            },
           
        )
        first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150, blank=False)
        last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150, blank=False)
        date_of_birth=models.DateField(_("date of birth"),blank=False)
        country=models.CharField(_("country"),max_length=250,blank=False)
        state=models.CharField(_("state"),max_length=250,blank=False)
        city=models.CharField(_("city"),max_length=250,blank=False)
        gender=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=GENDER_CHOICES,default="Male")
        
        profile_photo=models.ImageField(upload_to= upload_to)
        
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(
            _("staff status"),
            default=False,
            help_text=_("Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."),
        )
        is_active = models.BooleanField(
            _("active"),
            default=True,
            help_text=_(
                "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
                "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
            ),
        )
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("date joined"), default=timezone.now)
    
        objects = UserManager()
    
        EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
        USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name','date_of_birth','country','state','city','gender']
```

here is the error

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/core/post/add/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 809, in __iter__
        yield from iter(self._query)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 167, in __iter__
        yield self._align_results(doc)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 269, in _align_results
        if selected.table == self.left_table:
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/sql_tokens.py", line 133, in table
        print(alias2token[name].table)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/sql_tokens.py", line 133, in table
        print(alias2token[name].table)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/sql_tokens.py", line 133, in table
        print(alias2token[name].table)
      [Previous line repeated 917 more times]
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/sql_tokens.py", line 130, in table
        name = self.given_table
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/sql_tokens.py", line 142, in given_table
        name = self._token.get_real_name()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 361, in get_real_name
        return self._get_first_name(dot_idx)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 386, in _get_first_name
        return token.get_name()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 355, in get_name
        return self.get_alias() or self.get_real_name()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 344, in get_alias
        _, ws = self.token_next_by(t=T.Whitespace)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 244, in token_next_by
        return self._token_matching(funcs, idx, end)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 223, in _token_matching
        if func(token):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/sql.py", line 242, in <lambda>
        funcs = lambda tk: imt(tk, i, m, t)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/utils.py", line 100, in imt
        elif types and any(token.ttype in ttype for ttype in types):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/utils.py", line 100, in <genexpr>
        elif types and any(token.ttype in ttype for ttype in types):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlparse/tokens.py", line 19, in __contains__
        return item is not None and (self is item or item[:len(self)] == self)
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 76, in fetchone
        return self.result.next()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 797, in __next__
        result = next(self._result_generator)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 832, in __iter__
        raise exe from e
    djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 
    
            Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT %(0)s AS "a" FROM "Accounts_user" WHERE "Accounts_user"."username" = %(1)s LIMIT 1
    Params: (1, 'Priyanshu2002@')
    Version: 1.3.6
            Sub SQL: None
            FAILED SQL: None
            Params: None
            Version: None
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 81, in fetchone
        raise db_exe from e
    djongo.database.DatabaseError
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 686, in wrapper
        return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1892, in add_view
        return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1752, in changeform_view
        return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1798, in _changeform_view
        form_validated = form.is_valid()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 200, in errors
        self.full_clean()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 439, in full_clean
        self._post_clean()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 492, in _post_clean
        self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1447, in full_clean
        self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1499, in clean_fields
        setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 755, in clean
        self.validate(value, model_instance)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1088, in validate
        if not qs.exists():
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1226, in exists
        return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 592, in has_results
        return compiler.has_results()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1366, in has_results
        return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1409, in execute_sql
        val = cursor.fetchone()
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in inner
        with self:
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/anonymous/Documents/Project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 81, in fetchone
        raise db_exe from e
    django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

Comment: what this `userna=''` ??

Comment: Actual it was a variable which I used to store the username which I can use for adding path for image storage in imagefield